# The integral in my book is wrong, can you confirm?

Tags: integration

$$\int\sqrt{4z^2 - 4z + 2} dz$$

My book solution:

$$
\left( z-1/2 \right) \sqrt{z^2-z+1/2} + 1/4 \ln\left[ z - 1/2 +\sqrt{z^2-z+1/2} \right]
$$

My solution:

$$
\left( z-1/2 \right) \sqrt{z^2-z+1/2} + 1/4 \ln\left[ z - 1/2 +\sqrt{z^2-z+1/2} \right] + \underbrace{1/4 \ln 2}_\star
$$

Is not the term $\star$ missing in my book solution?

Comment: I don't know, but there's a $+C$ missing in both answers.

Comment: No, you're both right. The two functions differ by a constant.

Comment: Depends how you do substitution. Both are correct and as Ahmed says, the +C is missing which deals with the difference between the 2 solutions

Comment: you should add constant of integration $C$ to the final expression of following integration $$\int \sqrt{4z^2-4z+2}\ dz=\int 2\sqrt{z^2-z+\frac{1}{2}}\ dz=2\int \sqrt{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}}\ dz$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked the integral, but the starred term is just a constant that can be absorbed into your integration constant.

Comment: another thing to remember.